# Return several values inside for loop

Tags: python, return, generator, plotly-dash, yield

I have a function that must return several values using a for loop. I do not wish to store the values inside a list or a dict. Because of the use of the `return`, I only get the first value. How can I return all values successively? I tried using generators and `yield` but I'm not sure how to use it.

here is the function:

```
import random

def my_function():
    for i in range(3):
        return(dict(x=[[random.randint(0,10)]], y=[[random.randint(0,10)]]), 0)
```

Are generators and the use of `yield` suited for my need?

Comment: Yes but how do I use the result of the function afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `return` by `yield` to create a generator:

```
import random

def my_function():
    for i in range(3):
        yield dict(x=[[random.randint(0,10)]], y=[[random.randint(0,10)]]), 0

g = my_function()
for d in g:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
({'x': [[0]], 'y': [[10]]}, 0)
({'x': [[0]], 'y': [[1]]}, 0)
({'x': [[3]], 'y': [[0]]}, 0)
```

You can also use `next` to consume manually the next value:

```
g = my_function()
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))
print(next(g))  # Will raise a StopIteration exception
```

Output:

```
({'x': [[4]], 'y': [[4]]}, 0)
({'x': [[4]], 'y': [[9]]}, 0)
({'x': [[7]], 'y': [[2]]}, 0)
...
StopIteration:
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this gives you better understanding. next gives you value one by one and if you want all values wrap your function inside a list

```
import random

def my_function():
    for i in range(3):
        yield(dict(x=[[random.randint(0,10)]], y=[[random.randint(0,10)]]), 0)
a = my_function()
print(next(a)) # one by one
print(next(a))
print(list(my_function())) # get all values
```